# Select up to 5 random elements from list in python

Tags: python

Lets say I have:

```
In[2]: t = [1,2,3]
In[3]: import random
In[4]: random.sample(t,2)
Out[4]: [1, 3]
```

How do I Select UP TO 5 unique random elements? I tried:

```
In[5]: random.sample(t,5)
```

but this gives:

```
ValueError: sample larger than population
```

I would like to return all 3 element in the case of a list of only 3.

Comment: `random.sample(t, min(5, len(t)))`

Comment: You should really start posting your answers as answers. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe

```
random.sample(t, min([len(t), 5]))
```

Comment: No need to create a new `list`, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want them chosen randomly and that new_list is already defined,

```
import random

new_list += random.sample(old_list, 5)
```

If new_list is not already defined, then you can just do

```
new_list = random.sample(old_list, 5)
```

Comment: Thank for looking at this